# Logic, Predicate Calculus, and Proofs

Tags: logic

Is my proof correct?

***Premise:***

1) $\forall x ((Cx \land Gx) \rightarrow (Dx \land Rx))$

***Conclusion:***

$\therefore \forall x ((Cx \land Nx) \rightarrow (\forall y ((Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy) \rightarrow Rx))$

***Proof***

2) $(Ca \land Ga) \rightarrow (Da \land Ra)$ ***Universal Instantiation 1), a/x, flag a***

3) $((Ca \land Na)$ ***Conditional Proof Assumption***

4) $(\forall y (Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy)$ ***Conditional Proof Assumption***

5) $((Ca \land Na) \rightarrow Ga)$ ***Universal Instantiation 4)***

6) $Ca$ ***Simplification 3)***

7) $Ga$ ***Modus Ponens 3), 5)***

8) $(Ca \land Ga)$ ***Conjunction 6), 7)***

9) $(Da \land Ra)$ ***Modus Ponens 2), 8)***

10) $Ra$ ***Simplification 9)***

11) $((Ca \land Na) \rightarrow (\forall y ((Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy) \rightarrow Ra))$ ***Universal Generalization a/y***

12) $\forall x ((Cx \land Nx) \rightarrow (\forall y ((Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy) \rightarrow Rx))$ ***Universal Generalization a/x***

Comment: 2) is the conclusion ... so that should only appear as the last line of the proof. Now you infer things *from* the conclusion on line 3-b! That's obviously not right ...

Comment: Also, watch your indentations ... only indent more once you make an assumption.

Comment: I am using for 3-b Universal Instantiation. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, because you instantiate the universal on line 2 ... which is the conclusion that you need to prove! So line 2 should not be there in the first place. The conclusion is the last line of the proof ... now you are treating it as if it were a premise.

Comment: OK. Now I understand! Thank you! I will fix it!

Comment: @Bram28 Take a look when you have time. I believe that is better, but I am sure that I am missing something. In some way I just returned to my original post.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove 2) from the line numbers (again, that's the conclusion, so you don't want it to give a low number .. that's just confusing!)

Comment: It is fine! I understand that you do the best for helping math fans! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close!

A few mistakes:

You need to add an explicit line for the introduction (and flagging) of $a$ and do this *before* line 2.

You need to add a conditional proof to get the conditional $(\forall y (Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy) \rightarrow Ra$ before line 11)

Also, line 11 is a conditional proof, not a UG

Make sure to add line numbers for the justification of 11 and 12

So:

1) $\forall x ((Cx \land Gx) \rightarrow (Dx \land Rx))$

2) $\qquad$ flag $a$

3) $\qquad (Ca \land Ga) \rightarrow (Da \land Ra)$ ***Universal Instantiation 1), a/x***

4) $\qquad \qquad ((Ca \land Na)$ ***Conditional Proof Assumption***

5) $\qquad \qquad \qquad (\forall y (Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy)$ ***Conditional Proof Assumption***

6) $\qquad \qquad \qquad ((Ca \land Na) \rightarrow Ga)$ ***Universal Instantiation 5)***

7) $\qquad \qquad \qquad Ca$ ***Simplification 4)***

8) $\qquad \qquad \qquad Ga$ ***Modus Ponens 4), 6)***

9) $\qquad \qquad \qquad (Ca \land Ga)$ ***Conjunction 7), 8)***

10) $\qquad \qquad \qquad (Da \land Ra)$ ***Modus Ponens 3), 9)***

11) $\qquad \qquad \qquad Ra$ ***Simplification 10)***

12) $\qquad \qquad (\forall y (Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy) \rightarrow Ra$ ***Conditional Proof 5-11***

13) $\qquad ((Ca \land Na) \rightarrow (\forall y ((Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy) \rightarrow Ra))$ ***Conditional Proof 4-12***

14) $\forall x ((Cx \land Nx) \rightarrow (\forall y ((Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy) \rightarrow Rx))$ ***Universal Generalization a/x 2-13***

Comment: Thank you so much! I owe you my life!

Comment: Please accept my apologies for being a bad student!

Comment: @Beginner You are really not! You are actually doing pretty well!